# Why do ArcMap dimensions disapear when I close and reopen a map?

Tags: arcmap, extensions, dimensions, classextensions

I am trying to use the dimensions in ArcMap but after I dimension a map then close and reopen the map the dimensions are gone and I get a COM error, cannot initialize COM component when I try to edit the properties of the dimension feature class in ArcCatalog. Is there a way to save the dimensions so they do not disappear?
 [image]

I created a button to recreate the dim style with arcobjects, now I don't get COM initialize error but when I close and reopen arcmap, instead of dimension there are red polygons.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code I use to create the dimension feature class,

```
                IFeatureLayer pFeatureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)pBoundaryLayer;
                IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass;
                string strCatalogPath = GetCatalogPath(pFeatureClass);
                IWorkspace pWorkspace = FileGDBWorkspaceFromPropertySet(strCatalogPath);
                IObjectClassDescription ocDescription = new DimensionClassDescription();
                IFields pRequiredFields = ocDescription.RequiredFields;
                int intShapeFieldPosition = pRequiredFields.FindField("Shape");
                IField pShapeField = pRequiredFields.get_Field(intShapeFieldPosition);
                IGeometryDef pGeomDef = pShapeField.GeometryDef;
                IGeometryDefEdit pGeomDefEdit = (IGeometryDefEdit)pGeomDef;
                ISpatialReferenceFactory3 pSpatRefFac = new SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass();
                ISpatialReference pSpatRef = pSpatRefFac.CreateSpatialReference(6578);
                IProjectedCoordinateSystem pProSpatRef = (IProjectedCoordinateSystem)pSpatRef;
                ILinearUnit linUnit = pProSpatRef.CoordinateUnit;
                pGeomDefEdit.SpatialReference_2 = pSpatRef;
                IFeatureWorkspace pFeatWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)pWorkspace;
                string pName = "DIM";
                IFeatureClass pNewFeatureClass = pFeatWorkspace.CreateFeatureClass(pName.ToString(), pRequiredFields, ocDescription.InstanceCLSID, ocDescription.ClassExtensionCLSID, esriFeatureType.esriFTDimension, "Shape", "");
                ISchemaLock schemaLock = (ISchemaLock)pNewFeatureClass;
                try
                {
                    schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriExclusiveSchemaLock);

                    IDimensionClassExtension dimExtension = (IDimensionClassExtension)pNewFeatureClass.Extension;

                    dimExtension.ReferenceScale = 12000;

                    dimExtension.ReferenceScaleUnits = esriUnits.esriFeet;

                    IDimensionStyle dimensionStyle = new DimensionStyleClass();
                    dimensionStyle.Name = "BEARING_DISTANCE";
                    IDimensionStyleText dimText = (IDimensionStyleText)dimensionStyle;
                    string expression =  "def FindLabel ( [DIMLENGTH], [BEGINX] , [BEGINY] , [ENDX] , [ENDY]  ):" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "  import math" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "  dY = float([ENDY]) -float( [BEGINY])" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "  dX = float( [ENDX])-float( [BEGINX])" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "  azimuth = math.atan2(dX, dY) * 180 / math.pi" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "  if azimuth < 0:" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "    azimuth = azimuth + 360" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "    if azimuth > 270 and azimuth<= 360:" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      bearing = 360 - azimuth" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      minutes,seconds = divmod(bearing * 3600, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      dmsBearing = \"N \" + str(int(degrees)) + \"°\" + str(int(minutes)) + \"'\" + str(round(seconds, 2)) + \" W\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      return dmsBearing + \" \" + str(round(float( [DIMLENGTH]), 2))+\"'\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "    if azimuth > 180 and azimuth<= 270:" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      bearing = azimuth - 180" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      minutes,seconds = divmod(bearing * 3600, 60)"+ Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)"+ Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      dmsBearing = \"S \" + str(int(degrees)) + \"°\" + str(int(minutes)) + \"'\" + str(round(seconds, 2)) + \" W\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      return dmsBearing + \" \" + str(round(float( [DIMLENGTH]), 2))+\"'\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "    if azimuth > 90 and azimuth<= 180:" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      bearing = 180 - azimuth" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      minutes,seconds = divmod(bearing * 3600, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      dmsBearing = \"S \" + str(int(degrees)) + \"°\" + str(int(minutes)) + \"'\" + str(round(seconds, 2)) + \" E\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      return dmsBearing + \" \" + str(round(float( [DIMLENGTH]), 2))+\"'\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "    if azimuth >= 0 and azimuth<= 90:" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      minutes,seconds = divmod(azimuth * 3600, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      dmsBearing = \"N \" + str(int(degrees)) + \"°\" + str(int(minutes)) + \"'\" + str(round(seconds, 2)) + \" E\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      return dmsBearing + \" \" + str(round(float( [DIMLENGTH]), 2))+\"'\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "  else:" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "    if azimuth > 270 and azimuth<= 360:" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      bearing = 360 - azimuth" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      minutes,seconds = divmod(bearing * 3600, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      dmsBearing = \"N \" + str(int(degrees)) + \"°\" + str(int(minutes)) + \"'\" + str(round(seconds, 2)) + \" W\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      return dmsBearing + \" \" + str(round(float( [DIMLENGTH]), 2))+\"'\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "    if azimuth > 180 and azimuth<= 270:" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      bearing = azimuth - 180" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      minutes,seconds = divmod(bearing * 3600, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      dmsBearing = \"S \" + str(int(degrees)) + \"°\" + str(int(minutes)) + \"'\" + str(round(seconds, 2)) + \" W\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      return dmsBearing + \" \" + str(round(float( [DIMLENGTH]), 2))+\"'\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "    if azimuth > 90 and azimuth<= 180:" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      bearing = 180 - azimuth" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      minutes,seconds = divmod(bearing * 3600, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      dmsBearing = \"S \" + str(int(degrees)) + \"°\" + str(int(minutes)) + \"'\" + str(round(seconds, 2)) + \" E\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      return dmsBearing + \" \" + str(round(float( [DIMLENGTH]), 2))+\"'\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "    if azimuth >= 0 and azimuth<= 90:" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      minutes,seconds = divmod(azimuth * 3600, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      degrees,minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      dmsBearing = \"N \" + str(int(degrees)) + \"°\" + str(int(minutes)) + \"'\" + str(round(seconds, 2)) + \" E\"" + Environment.NewLine +
                                         "      return dmsBearing + \" \" + str(round(float( [DIMLENGTH]), 2))+\"'\"";

                    dimText.Expression = expression;
                    dimText.ExpressionSimple = false;
                    dimText.ExpressionParserName = "Python";
                    dimText.TextDisplay = esriDimensionTextDisplay.esriDimensionTDExpression;
                    dimText.ExtendLineOnFit = false;

                    stdole.IFontDisp iFont = new stdole.StdFontClass() as stdole.IFontDisp;
                    iFont.Name = "Arial";
                    iFont.Size = 8;
                    ITextSymbol txtSymbol = new TextSymbol();
                    txtSymbol.Font = iFont;
                    dimText.TextSymbol = txtSymbol;
                    IDimensionStyleDisplay dimDisplay = (IDimensionStyleDisplay)dimensionStyle;

                    dimDisplay.MarkerDisplay = esriDimensionDisplay.esriDimensionDisplayBoth;

                    IArrowMarkerSymbol mrkrSym = new ArrowMarkerSymbolClass();
                    mrkrSym.Size = 6;

                    IMarkerSymbol newMrkrSym = (IMarkerSymbol)mrkrSym;

                    dimDisplay.BeginMarkerSymbol = newMrkrSym;
                    dimDisplay.EndMarkerSymbol = newMrkrSym;

                    dimDisplay.MarkerFit = esriDimensionMarkerFit.esriDimensionMarkerFitText;
                    IDimensionStyles dimensionStyles = dimExtension.DimensionStyles;
                    dimensionStyles.AddStyle(dimensionStyle);



                }
                catch(COMException comExcept)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(comExcept.StackTrace.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {

                    schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriSharedSchemaLock);

                }
```

Update: I am still trying to persist the dimensions in arcmap I am now using the PersistenceHelper I am having some success persisting the shape but the text expression and line style are not persisting, to persist the DimensionStyleText and DimensionStyleDisplay do I add them to the struct and how do I do that since they are interfaces?

```
namespace CreateDimensions
{
    public class PersistExtension: ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension
    {

        private DimStyleStruct dimStyleClass;
        [Serializable()]
        public struct DimStyleStruct
        {
            public DimensionStyleClass dimStyle;

        }


        public PersistExtension()
        {

        }

        protected override void OnSave(Stream outStrm)
        {
            dimStyleClass = new DimStyleStruct();
            dimStyleClass.dimStyle = PersistDimClass.DimStyleClass;
            PersistenceHelper.Save<DimStyleStruct>(outStrm, dimStyleClass);
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(Stream inStrm)
        {
            dimStyleClass.dimStyle = new DimensionStyleClass();
            PersistenceHelper.Load<DimStyleStruct>(inStrm, ref dimStyleClass);
        }



    }
}
```

I have made a little more progress and I have rewritten my add-in as arcobjects extension, I use the load and save methods to write to the document stream and I am getting the style I want back in the map but the only thing missing is the custom expression to display bearing and distance.

```
    public void Save(IVariantStream Stream)
    {
        //TODO: Save extension related data to document stream
        if (DimStyleModel.Name != "")
        {
            Stream.Write(DimStyleModel.Name.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(DimStyleModel.Name.ToString());
            Stream.Write(DimStyleModel.RefScale);
            Stream.Write(DimStyleModel.Expression);
            Stream.Write(DimStyleModel.TextSymbol);
            Stream.Write(DimStyleModel.LineSymbol);
            Stream.Write(DimStyleModel.MrkrSymbol);
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Stream);
    }


    public void Load(IVariantStream Stream)
    {
        //TODO: Load persisted data from document stream
        if(Stream!=null)
        {
            string sName = "";
            int iRefScale = 0;
            string sExpression = "";
            ITextSymbol pTextSymbol = null;
            ILineSymbol pLineSymbol = null;
            IMarkerSymbol pMrkrSymbol = null;

            sName = (string)Stream.Read();
            iRefScale = (int)Stream.Read();
            sExpression = (string)Stream.Read();
            pTextSymbol = (ITextSymbol)Stream.Read();
            pLineSymbol = (ILineSymbol)Stream.Read();
            pMrkrSymbol = (IMarkerSymbol)Stream.Read();

            ILayer pLayer = ReturnLayerByName("DIM");
            IFeatureLayer pFeatureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)pLayer;
            IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass;
            ISchemaLock pSchemaLock = (ISchemaLock)pFeatureClass;
            try
            {
                pSchemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriExclusiveSchemaLock);
                IDimensionClassExtension pDimExt = (IDimensionClassExtension)pFeatureClass.Extension;
                pDimExt.ReferenceScale = iRefScale;
                pDimExt.ReferenceScaleUnits = esriUnits.esriFeet;
                IDimensionStyle pDimStyle = new DimensionStyleClass
                {
                    Name = sName
                };
                IDimensionStyleDisplay pNewDimDisplay = (IDimensionStyleDisplay)pDimStyle;
                pNewDimDisplay.MarkerDisplay = esriDimensionDisplay.esriDimensionDisplayBoth;
                pNewDimDisplay.DimensionLineSymbol = pLineSymbol;
                pNewDimDisplay.BeginMarkerSymbol = pMrkrSymbol;
                pNewDimDisplay.EndMarkerSymbol = pMrkrSymbol;
                pNewDimDisplay.MarkerFit = esriDimensionMarkerFit.esriDimensionMarkerFitText;
                pNewDimDisplay.MarkerDisplay = esriDimensionDisplay.esriDimensionDisplayBoth;
                pNewDimDisplay.DrawLineOnFit = false;
                IDimensionStyleText pNewDimText = (IDimensionStyleText)pDimStyle;
                pNewDimText.Expression = sExpression;
                pNewDimText.ExpressionParserName = "Python";
                pNewDimText.TextDisplay = esriDimensionTextDisplay.esriDimensionTDExpression;
                pNewDimText.TextSymbol = pTextSymbol;

                pDimExt.UpdateProperties();

                IDimensionStyles pDimStyles = pDimExt.DimensionStyles;
                pDimStyles.AddStyle(pDimStyle);
            }
            catch (COMException comExcept)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(comExcept.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                pSchemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriSharedSchemaLock);
            }


        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Stream);



    }
```

Next step I am going to tyr and add the expression in the load method,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that you're updating the class extension but you're missing the call to update what's persisted in the feature class. So, after you've updated the DimensionStyles, call [UpdateProperties](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IDimensionClassExtension_UpdateProperties.htm) on IDimensionClassExtension

Comment: I think I found another problem I am getting this error after I save and reopen a map w dimensions in it here is the error: at ESRI.Carto.IDimensionStyles.AddStyle() as DimToolbar.ApplicationExtension1.Load() in ...\DimToolbar
ApplicationExtension1.cs: line 254 when Load() adds the style to the DIMextension

Comment: You're getting the persistence load error?

Comment: Yes I am. I am going to go through and persist each object individually to see what exactly is having trouble loading. I am trying to persist a dimension with a text expression.

Comment: I found the issue I had for got `pNewDimText.ExpressionSimple = false;`